# Efficient lookup on fixed collection of vectors

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a fixed number (5) of vectors of structs (structs are inserted at runtime, a number can vary).
And i have a `enum class` which is used as a key for lookup. E.g.

```cpp
enum class CountryCode {
  kUS,
  // ...other 4
};

const std::vector<SomeStruct>& get_by_country_code(CountryCode cc);
```

I can use `std::unordered_map<CountryCode, std::vector<SomeStruct>, CustomHash>` with custom hash, but i think it not worth it for fixed size collection, which ordering is known before runtime.
What would be the most efficient way to store these 5 vectors and do a lookup by the `enum` value?

I'm also thinking about `std::tuple` but in my case values are not heterogeneous.

Comment: If the enumerators have the default values, can't you just use an array?

Comment: @DavisHerring does array of vectors considered a good practice?

Comment: It's the appropriate data structure, by definition, for a fixed-size collection of objects with fast index lookup.  If you want to be fancy, you could put them in a `std::array`, I guess?

Comment: @senloa "Good practice" with regards to arrays tends to be more about how the array is used than about what it is of (with one exception that would apply if your vectors will always be the same length as each other). However, I would clarify "array" to be [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) in preference to C-style array, probably.

Comment: @senloa if its fixed size , array is good practice than ordered_map.

Comment: Vectors are not the same length, sry if it is not clear from my question

Comment: Have a look at std::unordered_map (of vector), unordered map has O(1) lookup efficiency

Comment: @senloa No worries. I assumed the vectors would be different lengths. However, I figured the exception would be worth mentioning just in case.

Comment: Why do you need to use a custom hash?  **The hash operation applies to the KEY, not the VALUE.**   And enums are basically ints with a default hash operation this very close to being a no-op.  So unordered_map<CountryCode, vector<SomeStruct>`  is absolutely the way to go.

Comment: @selbie i thought hash was needed because my enum is `enum class` and cannot be implicitly converted to an int

Comment: @senloa - it absolutely casts to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the most efficient way to store these 5 vectors and do a lookup by the enum value?

An array. The default values of enum are 0,1,... which fit perfectly as the indices of an array.

Only small hurdle is that enum classes must be explicitly converted to the underlying integer.

> does array of vectors considered a good practice?

There's nothing particularly bad practice about them.

---

*If* the sizes of the vectors are known at the same time and they don't vary after creation, then there is a more efficient solution: Use a single vector that contains all objects partitioned by the country code. Then use an array of spans to the subvectors.

Comment: can you please add a code snipped for case with `std::span` that you mentioned? thx

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
using namespace std;


const int k_MAX_COUNTRY_CODE = 5;
enum class CountryCode: uint8_t {
    
    COUNTRY_CODE_0 = 0,
    COUNTRY_CODE_1 = 1,
    COUNTRY_CODE_2 = 2,
    COUNTRY_CODE_3 = 3,
    COUNTRY_CODE_4 = 4,
};


void printVector(vector<int>& f_vec){
    for(auto& el : f_vec){
        cout << el << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main() {

    CountryCode l_countryCode;
    array<vector<int>, k_MAX_COUNTRY_CODE> l_lookUP;
    vector<int> l_lookUP(k_MAX_COUNTRY_CODE);

    for(int i = 0; i < k_MAX_COUNTRY_CODE; i++){
        vector<int> tempVec((i+1)*2 , i + 534);
        l_lookUP[i] = tempVec;
    }

    printVector(l_lookUP[static_cast<int>(CountryCode::COUNTRY_CODE_4)]);
    printVector(l_lookUP[static_cast<int>(CountryCode::COUNTRY_CODE_3)]);
    printVector(l_lookUP[static_cast<int>(CountryCode::COUNTRY_CODE_1)]);
    printVector(l_lookUP[static_cast<int>(CountryCode::COUNTRY_CODE_2)]);
    return 0;
}
```

Like @eerorika suggested, I would also us an array for fast look up. I hope, this would be helpful.